# How to execute plugin after successful login in Wordpress

Tags: authentication, wordpress

Hello guys I need to execute some function (written as wordpress plugin) after user is logged in successfully i.e. all user credentials are stored such as cookies and sessions etc.

So my code is,

```
function do_this_shit() {
//some code here
}
add_action(???, 'do_this_shit');
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the wp_login hook:

```
add_action('wp_login', 'do_this_shit');
```

Can't find much in the docs about it, but here is it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login

Comment: Wordpress says function is deprecated http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login

Comment: Although, is that the function that's depreciated rather than the action hook?  It's still in this list which should be up-to-date: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: I also want to do same with logout i.e. some action after logout using add_action('wp_logut', 'do_this_shit_logout'); please guide me..

Comment: In the Action Reference link in my previous comment there's a wp_logout hook listed as well, so it should work just as you've posted (except wp_logout rather than wp_logut)

Comment: For later reference: the hook is save to use. It's just the function that is depreciated!